# Why are there no files in my release artifacts directory?

Tags: azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I created a .netcore 2.1 api project and set up Azure DevOps to deploy it to an On-Prem computer using the Windows Agent.

[image: api project files]

The folder agent_work\r1\a  was created on the machine running the agent, however there are no files in it.

I can see that a build did occur and that there is an artifact in my release

[image]

What did I miss doing?

[Update]

I can see in the agent job, there is a section which is about downloading an artifact.

It has the error message

```
There is no build available or the source is not accessible. You can select all artifacts or specify the list of artifacts to be downloaded below.
```

[Update]

Looks like I need to add a task to the job that is in a stage of my release.
And that task needs to copy the files I want to deploy.

Now the problem is knowing how to specify the source folder.
[image: the copy files task]

The strange thing is that it allows me to select a location and then rejects the selected location

[image: location selection]

There is help that says that if I leave the source folder empty, that will indicate the root of the repo. If I do this the deploy does not error but no files are deployed.

[Update]
I can see in the Get Sources of the Build the message "YOu are in 'detached Head' state. Maybe this has something to do with the problem.

[Update]
In the build pipeline I have
[image: the build]

[Update]

When I try to create a new build pipeline I get the following

[image: wizard screen]

I select the location to be Azure Repos and the Repository to be vste
then I the azure-pipelines.yml auto-generates as

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core web applications targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/vsts/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

[Update]

Looks like I might need to select Use The Visual Designer

[image: use the visual designer]

[Update]
From ollifant's comment I have found the Publish Artifact task.
Now to figure out how to populate it
[image: the publish artifact task]

[Update]
Uh Uh not looking great
[image: nothing will be added]

Comment: Do you have a build linked as an artifact source? Does that build publish any artifacts?

Comment: Ah, no artifacts, do I need them ?

Comment: maybe i am not selecting the correct template for the release

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54160675-fb01-4660-a568-d7c00c121b0a/cannot-link-an-artifact-source-to-a-release-definition?forum=TFService

Comment: I assume you want to copy the output of the project (basically "bin") to that machine, right? So I would first check the "build pipeline", which should have a "Publish Artifact" task. Is this the case? Are the artifacts for that build published?

Comment: checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/DevOps-Lab/DeployingtoOnPremisesServerswithVSTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not used the ASP NET Core (.NET framework) template when creating the agent job in the build template, so the project was not building correctly.

New build pipeline -> Use the visual designer -> Continue -> ASP.NET Core (.Net Framework)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=vsts